# Sentinel Policies to delete Workspace in Terraform cloud

Tags: terraform, sentinel

I am new to Sentinel ; want to know can we write policy to delete workspace into an org past x month? any Sample or reference will help.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that Sentinel is a policy as code framework. The goal of the policies are to provide pass/fail feedback to the Terraform workflow, not to actually make infrastructure changes, since that's Terraform's job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how one way of doing it:

1. Use the `tfrun` import
2. Look for the `workspace` block and attribute `created_at`.
   This will give you the timestamp when workspace was created
3. Use the `calender` import to get the current date/month
4. Use appropriate logic in your code to calculate the difference in current month and month when workspace was created
5. If the number > x(whatever timeframe you want) months, policy fails.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , let me try